# loop is too slow for IE7/8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, while-loop

I have a loop execution that needs to run in all browsers.

in chrome/ff etc the execution runs fast and fine. in IE it's slow and end's up dispatching a prompt saying a script is running slow (no good).

Any ideas on how to get around something like this? I mostly just need to get rid of the IE prompt for 7/8

** edit **

Here's code:

```
if(this.handicap()) {
    while(this.hasGraphChanged()) {
        this.gravity(this.separate());
    }
}
```

This is a VERY large project, so instead of listing all the code, I'll go for a quick explanation.

this.handicap: returns true if the browser if IE7/8
this.hasChanged: returns true/false depending if there is a change AFTER a draw update
this.gravity: processes drawing algorithm based on p1(array)

Comment: Could you give us an idea of the nature of the data you are looping, or what happens in each loop iteration?  Are you modifying DOM, parsing strings... whatchya doin'?  A code sample would be just berries.

Comment: @Jackson we'll need more information than that.....  are you asking to kill the IE 7/8 prompt or to help with loop performance?

Comment: If you had included the code with your question you'd probably have an answer by now :-)

Comment: @Jackson Apart from possibly moving some property accesses into local variables, without any idea of what the loop contains the question is of the form "how long is a piece of string?"

Comment: With this much info all I can think of to fix your problem is `<!--[if gte IE 7]>alert('You\'ll get another popup in a minute.');<![endif]-->`

Comment: I made an edit which adds code. This code works correctly. IE just whines because the code can take up to 6 seconds to run (only in IE7/8, others take about .002 - 2 seconds). I merely wish to somehow suppress the error message in IE as it's the only one with the issue.

Comment: hah, @JinX +1 for comic relief.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some asynchronous iteration technique instead of loops. Watch [Asynchronous Iteration Patterns](http://nodetuts.com/tutorials/19-asynchronous-iteration-patterns.html#video) by Pedro Teixeira for a nice introduction. It uses Node.js but you can use the same patterns in the browser.

Comment: Good call. I might try this (or something like it). I was originally wondering if I should go for a recursive function. either way, Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

What exactly does the loop do? Is the number of iterations deterministic? If this is something which is causing the browser to hang you may want to consider javascript worker-threads https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers (although I'm not sure which browsers currently support this feature).

Comment: Not IE 8 or below, you'll need to wait for IE9 . .

Comment: Pretty cool (didn't know about these), but unfortunately I need a solution which is graceful when applied to IE7/8 as @JinX mentioned. However, I'm going to keep this solution in mind for future project. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, I have only ever used them on a recent project where the client required only compatibility with Google Chrome.