# Parsing very large JSON strings in IE causing problems

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer

I'm parsing a 2MB JSON string in IE8. The `JSON.Parse` line is taking a little while to return and IE8 shows a message asking the user if they want to abort the script.

Is there any way I can suppress this message? (or somehow speed up JSON.Parse)

I know about Microsoft [KB175500](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175500), however this is not suitable as my target users will not have administrator access to make the registry modifications on their SOE machines.

Comment: is your JSON from 3rd party or your own host ?

Comment: It's a local file. The JSON string is already stored in a variable in JS - the line which is causing trouble is the line which parses the string variable into a javascript object.

Comment: so does your user uploads the file ?

Comment: @Ozzah - I would limit the size of the response. Maybe you could page the results somehow.

Comment: so by AJAX i am assuming its from your own sever, you might consider lazy load then. create multiple objects.
PS. it's more of optimization so the code will help alot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same question. Apparently there is no way to suppress the message, but there are tricks to make IE *think* it's still working by using an [asynchronous iteration pattern](http://nodetuts.com/tutorials/19-asynchronous-iteration-patterns.html#video) (dead link, view comments below).

This comes from an answer to one of my questions:
[loop is too slow for IE7/8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095161/loop-is-too-slow-for-ie7-8)

Comment: Well that's dumb. I searched google 'parallel iteration javascript' for and found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413857/whats-the-smartest-cleanest-way-to-iterate-async-over-arrays-or-objs

Answer (score 0):

If the browser is unhappy with how long the JSON parser is taking, there are only four choices here I know of:

1. Get a faster JSON parser that doesn't take so long.
2. Break up your JSON data into smaller pieces so you are only parsing smaller pieces at once.
3. Modify a JSON parser to work in chunks so it can parse part of the data in one chunk, then on a short timeout, parse the next chunk, etc...  This will prevent the browser prompt, but is probably a lot of work to write/modify a JSON parser that works this way.
4. If you can be sure the content is safe, then you could see if using eval instead of a JSON parser works around the issue.