# Whats the smartest / cleanest way to iterate async over arrays (or objs)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Thats how I do it:

```
function processArray(array, index, callback) {
    processItem(array[index], function(){
        if(++index === array.length) {
            callback();
            return;
        }
        processArray(array, index, callback);
    });
};

function processItem(item, callback) {
    // do some ajax (browser) or request (node) stuff here

    // when done
    callback();
}

var arr = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];

processArray(arr, 0, function(){
    console.log("done");
});
```

Is it any good? How to avoid those spaghetti'ish code?

Comment: With jQuery, you can use `$.each([...], function() {...});` and there will be similar methods in the other JS libraries.

Comment: Yes, but those are synchronous. Aron is asking about async loops, a much more interesting problem!

Comment: 2016 and I used this today. Should probably look at ES6 but... thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Checkout the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library, it's made for control flow (async stuff) and it has a lot of methods for array stuff: each, filter, map. Check the documentation on github. Here's what you probably need:

**each(arr, iterator, callback)**

Applies an iterator function to each item in an array, in parallel. The iterator is called with an item from the list and a callback for when it has finished. If the iterator passes an error to this callback, the main callback for the `each` function is immediately called with the error.

**eachSeries(arr, iterator, callback)**

The same as `each` only the iterator is applied to each item in the array in series. The next iterator is only called once the current one has completed processing. This means the iterator functions will complete in order.

Comment: the functions are called "each" and "eachSeries" https://github.com/caolan/async#each

Comment: Keep in mind that his comment was written two years before yours though @LaurentDebricon

Comment: how do you loop infinitely over an array, for example
async.eachSeries([1,2,3]) i want to return to 1 after 3 , how to do that

Answer (score 17):

As pointed in some answer one can use "async" library. But sometimes you just don't want to introduce new dependency in your code. And below is another way how you can loop and wait for completion of some asynchronous functions.

```
var items = ["one", "two", "three"];

// This is your async function, which may perform call to your database or
// whatever...
function someAsyncFunc(arg, cb) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        cb(arg.toUpperCase());
    }, 3000);
}

// cb will be called when each item from arr has been processed and all
// results are available.
function eachAsync(arr, func, cb) {
    var doneCounter = 0,
        results = [];
    arr.forEach(function (item) {
        func(item, function (res) {
            doneCounter += 1;
            results.push(res);
            if (doneCounter === arr.length) {
                cb(results);
            }
        });
    });
}

eachAsync(items, someAsyncFunc, console.log);
```

Now, running `node iterasync.js` will wait for about three seconds and then print `[ 'ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE' ]`. This is a simple example, but it can be extended to handle many situations.

Comment: It is incredible that this answer had zero upvotes at the that of this comment.

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: The output might not necessarily be in 1,2,3 order.

Comment: Does not treat empty array case, and counter seems unnecessary because you have the length of "results"

Answer (score 9):

As correctly pointed out, you have to use setTimeout, for example:

```
each_async = function(ary, fn) {
    var i = 0;
    -function() {
        fn(ary[i]);
        if (++i < ary.length)
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, 0)
    }()
}


each_async([1,2,3,4], function(p) { console.log(p) })
```

Comment: Why is there a "-" (minus) before the second `function()`?

Comment: @AaronDigulla `-function()` causes the immediate function to be considered an expression. It's not really any different than wrapping the function in parentheses, which is another way of making it a valid expression. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341698/javascript-plus-sign-in-front-of-function-name

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to handle async iteration of arrays (or any other iterable) is with the await operator (only in async functions) and for of loop.

```js
(async function() {
 for(let value of [ 0, 1 ]) {
  value += await(Promise.resolve(1))
  console.log(value)
 }
})()
```

You can use a library to convert any functions you may need which accept callback to return promises.

Comment: I found this approach to be more clean.

Answer (score 1):

In modern JavaScript there are interesting ways to extend an Array into an async itarable object.

Here I would like to demonstrate a skeleton of a totally new type `AsyncArray` which extends the `Array` type by inheriting it's goodness just to become an async iterable array.

This is only available in the modern engines. The code below uses the latest gimmicks like the [private instance fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#private_instance_fields) and [`for await...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of).

If you are not familiar with them then I would advise you to have a look at the above linked topics in advance.

```
class AsyncArray extends Array {
  #INDEX;
  constructor(...ps){
    super(...ps);
    if (this.some(p => p.constructor !== Promise)) {
      throw "All AsyncArray items must be a Promise";
    }
  }
  [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    this.#INDEX = 0;
    return this;
  };
  next() {
    return this.#INDEX < this.length ? this[this.#INDEX++].then(v => ({value: v, done: false}))
                                     : Promise.resolve({done: true});
  };
};
```

So an Async Iterable Array must contain promises. Only then it can return an iterator object which with every `next()` call returns a promise to eventually `resolve` into an object like `{value : "whatever", done: false}` or `{done: true}`. So basically everything returned is a promise here. The `await` abstraction unpacks the value within and gives it to us.

Now as I mentioned before, this `AsyncArray` type, since extended from `Array`, allows us to use those Array methods we are familiar with. That should simplify our job.

Let's see what happens;

```js
class AsyncArray extends Array {
  #INDEX;
  constructor(...ps){
    super(...ps);
    if (this.some(p => p.constructor !== Promise)) {
      throw "All AsyncArray items must be a Promise";
    }
  }
  [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    this.#INDEX = 0;
    return this;
  };
  next() {
    return this.#INDEX < this.length ? this[this.#INDEX++].then(v => ({value: v, done: false}))
                                     : Promise.resolve({done: true});
  };
};

var aa = AsyncArray.from({length:10}, (_,i) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,i*1000,[i,~~(Math.random()*100)])));

async function getAsycRandoms(){
  for await (let random of aa){
    console.log(`The Promise at index # ${random[0]} gets resolved with a random value of ${random[1]}`);
  };
};

getAsycRandoms();
```

Answer (score 0):

### For modern Node.js:

To iterate through a collection truly asynchronously, you can try my tiny package with zero dependencies, compatible with ESM and CJS modules with .d.ts typings. Check the code it's really tiny.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-to-async-iterable

**You can use it just like this:**

```js
for await(const el of new AsyncTimeIterator(arrayOfObjects)){
  ...
}
```

---

You can't just use `for await of` loop because of the JavaScript engines' microtasks and macrotasks nature.
In a brief, you won't get new HTTP requests and let other timers' callbacks to be executed with this code:

```js
for await(const el of array){
  ...
}
```

You force V8 or the other engine to execute all the microtasks (your loop iteration) and when the loop completes you'll unblock the event loop and be ready to receive HTTP connections. So this code is completely useless.