# How should I call functions in order to execute them one after the other?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I am trying to develop mobile application and I use the framework (PhoneGap), I have sql operation so I choose this separate, and each operation put under a function and these functions will be called in order.

my problem that these functions are not calling in order

Comment: Functions that have to be called in specific order is not a good design. If they have to be called in order, the code should be structured so that you can't call them out of order by mistake.

Comment: @JanHudec: I did not understand

Comment: Well, you didn't include any sample, so I can't show you anything specific.

Comment: @JanHudec

for(i=0;i<lg;i++) 
{ d=fct1_SQL(i); fct2_SQL(d); }

Comment: a) Sample is best provided by _editing the question_, since you can format it nicely there. b) That's even uglier design than I thought, but without seeing what those functions are nobody can suggest a better one.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript SQL libraries tend to be asynchronous and use callbacks. Put the call to the next function in the callback you use in the previous function.

Comment: I have already done that, but at some point I need to call more than one function in a loop.

Comment: for(i=0;i<lg;i++)
{
d=fct1_SQL(i);
fct2_SQL(d);
}

Comment: See [Whats the smartest / cleanest way to iterate async over arrays (or objs)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413857/whats-the-smartest-cleanest-way-to-iterate-async-over-arrays-or-objs)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript code is generally asynchronous, to ensure code execution order generally callbacks are used, a function in a library  may look like this:

```
function doWork(params, callback){
  //do stuff

  //when done call the callback function
  callback()
}
```

This allows you to use this function and pass a function to be called when this function has finished doing what it needs to do.

```
doWork(params, function() { 
  //this code is not executed until doWork has completed and called its callback 
})
```

Have a look at the library you are using they probably use callbacks