# create an asynchronous each loop in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

This is my each loop:-

```
var image_obj = {};

$(".wrapper").each(function (index, data) {
  var dfile = this.getElementsByClassName('image')[0];
  file = dfile.files[0];
  if(file != null) {
    var fr = new FileReader();


fr.onload = function (e) {

          img = new Image();
          img.onload = function (k) {
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            objindex = "obj_" + index;
            image_obj[objindex] = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

          };
          img.src = fr.result;
        };
        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
    });
```

I need the index of my each loop to save base_64 encoded image to an object.

But the index is not showing up in order as each loop execution finishes before reaching `canvas.getContext("2d");`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the smartest / cleanest way to iterate async over arrays (or objs)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413857/whats-the-smartest-cleanest-way-to-iterate-async-over-arrays-or-objs)

Answer (score 0):

One big problem is that you need to declare `img` inside your outer function:

```
$(".wrapper").each(function (index, data) {
  var img;
```

The reason is that otherwise, `img` is a global. The `img` variable captured in your `onload` function just contains the current value of that global, which is just whatever the most recent `each` call assigned it to (likely the last wrapper in the jquery object). Then when `onload` is called, it writes the wrong image into the canvas. By declaring the variable, you ensure that each outer function scope has its very own `img` variable for your `onload` functions to capture, which they'll then use when they're actually applied.

**Edit** If you want to ensure that the outputed order is right, you should just sort it out at the end, since you don't control when `onload` runs; that's actually the beauty of it. I'd do something like this:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
if (typeof(image_obj.images) == "undefined")
  image_obj.images = [];
image_obj.images[index] = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

Or just make `image_obj` itself an array and just do:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
image_arr[index] = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

Depending on whether you need the object as a container for other stuff.

Since that's an array, not an object, the images will be in order.

**Edit 2**

So the problem now is that you get holes in your array if some of the files aren't there. Let's make that not happen:

```
var index = -1;
$(".wrapper").each(function (_, data) {
  ...
  if(file != null) {
    var fr = new FileReader();
    index++;
    var localIndex = index; //to capture locally

    fr.onload = function (e) {
      ...
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      image_arr[localIndex] = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
      ..
```

Comment: Still the order of index is 0,2,1  where it should be 0,1,2

Comment: Sure, because your `onload` calls just run when when they run. You should make `image_obj` an array, and then they'll be in the correct order. I was just focussing on the part where you might not be drawing what you thought you were drawing. I'll edit.

Comment: Yeah I need the  order to retrieve them as there are other things associated with each of them. I need to retrieve them in order conbine them with other form fields and then do an ajx call.

Comment: BTW there is no issue on drawing the issue is with index.

Comment: If you didn't see an issue drawing the wrong thing, then you just got lucky about the timing. See my edit for the an easy way to order the images; just use an array.

Comment: In fact, I'm pretty sure the `var` thing would have been a nasty bug; are you sure that without it, your URLs aren't all the same? Because that's how the code runs in my head.

Comment: Problem here is that if file == null it will not go inside and my array will get out of order.One more issue is that the execution is not asynchronous.

Comment: Hmm, right. Increment index inside of that check instead of using the one provided to your `each` callback.

Comment: I tried that one too but it doesn't increment my counter remains 0 all the time.

Comment: Still the order of index is same 0,2,1